# Laravel markdown mail - multiple templates. How to define path for @component('mail::*')

Tags: php, laravel, email, notifications, laravel-notification

As detailed in config/mail.php, the default markdown mail folder is in views/vendor/mail

```php
'markdown' => [
    'theme' => 'default',

    'paths' => [
        resource_path('views/vendor/mail'),
    ],
],
```

I have created a new template in `views/templates/1/mail`. Change the path in the config and this works fine.

How can I use both the default vendor/mail folder as well as my new template for different notifications?

Adding my path to the mail config kind of works, but this is more to add additional files to the current template and requires that all files have unique names across every folder.

I can of course namespace the entire template path inside each blade file through to the HTML folder, but is there a more elegant way to hook up the `mail::xxxx` helper?

```
@component('templates/1/mail/html.layout')
```

Comment: Did you find a way to solve this issue? I have the same problem.

Answer (score 3):

To use `mail::button` type format, you have to create hint for that keyword, which is nowhere to be found in Laravel documentation.

As an alternate solution, this is how I'm using multiple layout for the Laravel notification:

1. Clone you existing **mail** (project/resources/views/vendor/mail) folder and customize the new layout. Inside **mail** folder you can customize the complete design. Files under this folder, provides blocks level changes to your email body.
2. Next, You have to clone *email.blade.php* file under **notifications** (project/resources/views/vendor/notifications), and customize it as per your need. This single file is the skeleton of your email.
3. Modify your email notifications to add `view()` or `markdown()` as per your need. In your Notification's 'toMail' function, chain the below line:

   ```
   ->view('vendor.notifications.custom_layout')
   ```

So, it will look like this:

```
return (new MailMessage)
            ->subject(__('emails/registration.subject'))
            ->greeting(__('emails/registration.failed.greetings', ['recipient' => $this->learner->username]))
            ->line(__('emails/registration.line_1'))
            ->line(__('emails/registration.line_2', ['username' => $this->username]))
            ->action(__('action.log_in'), "https://{$loginURL}")
            ->view('vendor.notifications.custom_layout');
```

4. All the file naming convention will change from `mail::message` to `vendor.custom_layout.html.message`

This is how your custom file (under **notifications** folder) will look like:

```
@component('vendor.custom_layout.html.message')
{{-- Greeting --}}
@if (! empty($greeting))
# {{ $greeting }}
@else
@if ($level == 'error')
# @lang('Whoops!')
@else
# @lang('Hello!')
@endif
@endif

{{-- Intro Lines --}}
@foreach ($introLines as $line)
{!! $line !!}

@endforeach

{{-- Action Button --}}
@isset($actionText)
@component('vendor.custom_layout.html.button', ['url' => $actionUrl])
    {{ $actionText }}
@endcomponent
@endisset

{{-- Outro Lines --}}
@foreach ($outroLines as $line)
{!! $line !!}
@endforeach

{{-- Salutation --}}
@if (! empty($salutation))
{{ $salutation }}
@else
{{ __('label.thank_you') }}<br>{{ __('label.xyz_team') }}
@endif

{{-- Subcopy --}}
@isset($actionText)
@component('vendor.custom_layout.html.subcopy')
{!! __('emails/common.footer_notice', ['actionText' => $actionText]) !!}
[{{ $actionUrl }}]({!! $actionUrl !!})
@endcomponent
@endisset
@endcomponent
```

These are the only changes which are required to make a customized view for your emails.